# Store more than 24 hours in a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I work in a bizarre and irrational industry where we need to be able to represent the time of day as 06:00:00 to 30:00:00 instead of 0:00:00 to 24:00:00. Is there any way to do this using the DateTime type? If I try to construct a date time with an hour value greater than 24 it throws an exception.

Comment: I'm intrigued. What industry is this?

Comment: @JohnFx - it is april 1st after all

Comment: @JohnFx - I'm guessing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TARDIS ?

Comment: Let's say you have such a DateTime called WeirdDateTime. Would the time corresponding to DateTime 2010-01-20 01:00:00 show as 2010-01-19 25:00:00 in your WeirdDateTime class?

Answer (score 10):

I think this should be a presentation issue only.

Allow your users to input data in this weird format, and immediately convert it to UTC. Do all calculations on the UTC times. Then create a ToString method to convert the results back into your weird format. You will probably also need some other utility methods and properties such as an implementation of `WeirdDateTime.Day`.

You could write a wrapper class around a DateTime and have all the conversion and utility methods you need on that class. I've had a go at starting it - by implementing parsing from a string in weird format. This isn't production code ready by any means, but perhaps it can give you a few ideas of how you could approach this:

```
class WeirdDateTime
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public WeirdDateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, DateTimeKind kind)
    {
        if (hour < 6 || hour >= 30)
            throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid WeirdDateTime", "hour");

        bool addDay;
        if (hour >= 24)
        {
            addDay = true;
            hour -= 24;
        }
        else
        {
            addDay = false;
        }

        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, kind);
        if (addDay)
            dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(1);

        DateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public static WeirdDateTime Parse(string s)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})");
        Match match = regex.Match(s);
        if (!match.Success)
            throw new FormatException("Not a valid WeirdDateTime");

        int[] parts = match.Groups.Cast<Group>()
            .Skip(1)
            .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value))
            .ToArray();

        int year = parts[0];
        int month = parts[1];
        int day = parts[2];
        int hour = parts[3];
        int minute = parts[4];
        int second = parts[5];

        return new WeirdDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Write this!");
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WeirdDateTime weirdDateTime = WeirdDateTime.Parse("2010-01-19 27:00:00");
        DateTime dateTimeUtc = weirdDateTime.DateTime.ToUniversalTime();
        Console.WriteLine(dateTimeUtc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about use a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) instead ?

```
DateTime departure = new DateTime(2010, 6, 12, 18, 32, 0);
DateTime arrival = new DateTime(2010, 6, 13, 22, 47, 0);
TimeSpan travelTime = arrival - departure;  
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} = {2}", arrival, departure, travelTime);
```

Then use the `TotalHours` property of the TimeSpan obj

Comment: I did try using TimeSpan, however any hours over 24 will be rolled over into the day. So for example 36:00:00 would end up being 1:12:00:00 as a TimeSpan.

Comment: How is this a problem? Just use yourTimeSpan.TotalHours.

Comment: @Rob use the TotalHours property of the TimeSpan obj then.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you can do exactly what you're looking for, but I expect that you could make your own DateTime class that simply adds +6 hrs to the value. i.e. stores 00 - 24 internally, but the get/set methods make it seem like 06 - 30.

Comment: Yes you can inherit from the existing date time class and override the methods/properties that involve the hour

Comment: @Chris Simpson, you can't inherit from the existing DateTime struct.

Comment: Need to use TimeSpan for something like this.

Comment: @šljaker ah, I didn't know that. it would just have to be a wrapper class then

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be using TimeSpan, not DateTime.
2. The format options for TimeSpan is

   a: [days].[hours]:[minutes]:[seconds].[fractional seconds]

   b: [days].[hours]:[minutes]:[seconds]

   c: [days].[hours]:[minutes]

   d: [days].[hours]

   e: [days]

   f: [hours]:[minutes]:[seconds].[fractional seconds]

   g: [hours]:[minutes]:[seconds]

   h: [hours]:[minutes]

Answer (score 0):

Just have your business logic store/return DateTime.Hours.Add(6).  You'll have to be aware of this in your display logic.

Answer (score 0):

how 'bout using a normal DateTime to store the actual time, and writing a new class which stores (or derives from ) a DateTime, and has a ToString() which adjusts the output.

Answer (score 0):

I for calculate Employ work hours use this function:

```
     public string SumHours(string TimeIn, string TimeOut)
    {
        var parts = TimeIn.Split(':');
        var hours = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);
        var minutes = Int32.Parse(parts[1]);
        var result = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, 0);
        TimeIn = result.ToString();

        TimeSpan Hour1 = TimeSpan.Parse(TimeIn);
        TimeSpan Hour2 = TimeSpan.Parse(TimeOut);
        Hour1 = Hour1.Add(Hour2);

        string HourtoStr = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", (Hour1.Days * 24 + Hour1.Hours), Hour1.Minutes, Hour1.Seconds);
        return HourtoStr;
    }
```